# Analytics e-commerce conversion ratio not showing

Tags: google-analytics

> Missing e-commerce data Display mywebsite.nl - General no filter is
>   configured for e-commerce, but no data is transmitted.

This is the error Analytics is giving me. (translated from Dutch)

Every graph is showing normal results. except this one:

[image]

conversion rate of e-commerce.

It used to work before. If i go way back to another date it displays data.
somehow it stopped working and i dont know how its possible.

Comment: are you able to provide us with the query that would fetch this data?

Comment: We need more information, just looking if looks like a bug. Try to contact support is you're a premium user if you're not  add a second Ga Snippet and compare the data between both implementations.

Comment: ended up using this video then solved it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OFNe3RSYZjU @KemenPaulosPlaza